Why does adding a Column to this layout makes the app crash?
After many hours of debugging and code-simplification, my app looks like the following:

just a bunch of unpopulated cards that you can navigate around using direction arrows, the problem is that if you move fast enough (some strokes per second), the app crashes with the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutCoordinate operations are only valid when isAttached is true
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.getParentLayoutCoordinates(NodeCoordinator.kt:255)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutCoordinatesKt.findRootCoordinates(LayoutCoordinates.kt:180)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusTraversalKt.focusRect(FocusTraversal.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.findBestCandidate-4WY_MpI(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.searchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:166)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.generateAndSearchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:141)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.searchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:173)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.access$searchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt$generateAndSearchChildren$1.invoke(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt$generateAndSearchChildren$1.invoke(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:146)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutBeyondBoundsModifierLocal.layout-o7g1Pn8(LazyLayoutBeyondBoundsModifierLocal.kt:111)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.BeyondBoundsLayoutKt.searchBeyondBounds--OM-vw8(BeyondBoundsLayout.kt:45)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.generateAndSearchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:146)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.twoDimensionalFocusSearch--OM-vw8(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:74)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.twoDimensionalFocusSearch--OM-vw8(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:70)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusTraversalKt.focusSearch-sMXa3k8(FocusTraversal.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusOwnerImpl.moveFocus-3ESFkO8(FocusOwnerImpl.kt:180)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView$keyInputModifier$1.invoke-ZmokQxo(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:242)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView$keyInputModifier$1.invoke(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:237)
    at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputNode.onKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:80)
    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusOwnerImpl.dispatchKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(FocusOwnerImpl.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:696)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:476)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1861)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4085)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.kt:103)
    at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:85)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.kt:117)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:390)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5960)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5828)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5498)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5555)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5531)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5689)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3287)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2829)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2820)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3264)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

This is what the code look at this point:
import android.app.Activity

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

import androidx.tv.material3.Card

@Composable
fun CatalogBrowser(
    context: Activity,
) {
    val rows = List(4) { rowIndex ->
        List(20) { columnIndex -> "Item $rowIndex-$columnIndex" }
    }

    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(rows) { rowItems ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                LazyRow {
                    items(rowItems) { item ->
                        Card(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(40.dp) // Space between cards
                                .width(150.dp).height(200.dp),  // Size of each card
                            onClick = {},
                        ) {
    }}}}}}
}

It looks like that having
Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) 

is the ultimate reason of the crash. Now, because i don't like to waste hours in debug without learning anything, would anyone be kind enough to explain to me what is wrong with Column placed in that position? Is it a bug in the libraries? Should I raise this issue with Google?
P.S. I'm not sure about the reason why I had a Column inside a TvLazyColumn, I'm still learning Composable and Kotlin and it may have been a copy paste error, but nevertheless, this bug was really hard to catch

I don't know about the error but I think the Column inside of your LazyColumn is redundant.

your code worked fine for me,  maybe it's just a versioning issue. try updating the dependencies (ref).

@Yamin yeah, as i said, i didn't notice the LazyColumn in the Column until i simplified the code, i already removed and it works fine, i just want to understand what is going on.

Could you also add the version numbers of the libraries in the question? A lot of unattached node issues were fixed in compose ui v1.7.0-xxx. If you are still on 1.6.x version, can you check if this happens with 1.7.0-xxx version as well?
